# Are there unique weapons/items that must be pickpocketed from NPCs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I'm playing Dragonborn DLC, and I just used my last skill point to unlock [Misdirection](https://skyrim.fandom.com/wiki/Misdirection), a Pickpocket skill that lets me pickpocket equipped weapons.

I was pretty lucky because the first time I used it was on this mystery merchant, [Falas Selvayn](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Falas_Selvayn), which owned a unique bow, the [Glass Bow of the Stag Prince](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Glass_Bow_of_the_Stag_Prince). And I had to pickpocket him, since it's labeled as an essential NPC so he can't be killed.

So I'm wondering... did I miss other unique weapons that can be obtained only pickpocketing (and without killing) an NPC?
The question could be extended including [Perfect Touch](https://skyrim.fandom.com/wiki/Perfect_Touch), that lets the player pickpocket equipped items.